# Probability and combinations intuition

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This was a question randomly given in my class by my teacher:

In a class of 10, each student has the same chance of getting a scholarship. Find the probability that exactly 3 of the students will get a scholarship?

The answer was :

$$10C3\left(\frac12\right)^3\left(\frac12\right)^7$$

But I can't seem to get the intuition of why this is so. I understand that $10C3$ means that we are choosing 3 students out of 10 but I don't get how this is used here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to think about the problem: consider bit (binary) strings of length ten,

$$b_1b_2...b_{10}$$

where each $b_i \in \{0, 1\}$. Suppose we make the following interpretation: $b_i = 1$ if and only if student $i$ gets a scholarship. From the assumptions, any such string is equally likely, and there are $2^{10}$ of them. How many strings have exactly three $1$'s? $10\,C\,3$. So the probability of exactly three students getting a scholarship is

$$\dfrac{10\,C\,3}{2^{10}}$$

Answer (score 1):

The prob. for each student to get a scholarship is $\frac{1}{2}$ and the prob for two students to get a scholarship is independent, therefore define:

$X = # of students that got scolarship$

then X is a r.v. and we have due to independency $X \sim Bin(10,\frac{1}{2})$ and we looking for $P(X=3)$ which is exactly the answer.